# Open app from url in Mobile safari fails with .zip extension

Tags: objective-c, ios, mobile-safari

I have used the info in this great post [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290) to get my app launching from Mail with both **mydoc.foo**  and the compressed version **mydoc.foo.zip** which auto-magically decompresses into my apps sandbox.

I can open a url such as **http://blah.com/shared/mydoc.foo** into my app with Safari but when the url is **http://blah.com/shared/mydoc.foo.zip** I get the message **Unable to open Document** when I use the **Open in MyApp** button on the loaded page.

Im wondering what needs adding to my info.plist to get this particular URL working as Safari recognises my app as the receiver for this extension set and Mail behaves perfectly well.

Its not hitting the 
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to accept .zip files and the page you've linked accepts .gz files, make sure you've specified a `com.pkware.zip-archive` UTI instead of `org.gnu.gnu-zip-archive`.

Comment: Yes . I have that UTI specified in my plist rather than the gzip type